# modifying previously executed commands on linux

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to modify a previously run command with slightly different arguments. Is there a quick way of reaching the argument which is somewhere  between in the big command, instead of going to that place from beginning (or end) of the command?

Currently I wrap the big command into some small command and pass the argument to the wrapper command.

Was wondering if there was any other way.

Comment: Add those commands how you executed to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press <kbd>↑</kbd> to bring the last line;

Then you can jump over the arguments with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.
(if you're on Mac it's <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>)

You may also type `!:1` to refer to the first argument in the previous entry, or `!:2` to refer to the second argument, and so on.